# Migrating from Cloudbees to other service for @Run

Tags: java, mysql, migration, cloudbees

As many of us here have probably had, I've received a message from CloudBees stating that the @Run service will soon be discontinued.

I have to migrate elsewhere and need a Dummy's Guide on how to set up a new platform where I can run my service.  Are there any guides out there?  All I get from Google is CloudBees' own guide which is too vague for me.

I'm running a java app, uploaded as a War connected to a MySQL DB.

Could any of you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Give a look at official [migration documentation](http://www.cloudbees.com/faq-customers-runcloud) (point 2 has a link to google doc containing some info)
2) Check the section called "Migration CloudBees Applications" and select the provider you would like to migrate to 
3) Type in google (or your prefered search engine): `"CloudBees to <selected provider> migration"`
(you should end-up with something like [this](https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-migrate-your-java-app-to-openshift/) or [this](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/9/12/welcome_to_heroku_cloudbees_developers).. I'm not advertising, those are just random examples)
4) Start following the steps, and if you will have an problem don't hesitate to ask more specific questions